# How to know Text ix replaced or not in a RichText Box

Tags: c#, richtextbox

This is my code that i use:

```
Richtextbox.Text = Richtextbox.Text.Replace(ReplaceOldWord, ReplaceNewWord);
```

How do I know if the old word is replaced with new word or not....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist way is to check if text changed:

```
    String text = Richtextbox.Text.Replace(ReplaceOldWord, ReplaceNewWord);
    if(RichTextBox.Text != text)
    {
        Richtextbox.Text = text;
        DoSomething();
    }
```

The second is to use [TextChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx). This event will rize only if richtextbox text changes.

```
public Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    RichTextBox.TextChanged += Richtextbox_TextChanged;
}

private void Richtextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this but if you have a textbox, i persume that you have GUI, just try to print the word there or use a `streamwriter` for saving the words in a text-file.

Answer (score 1):

If would make a call to [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) before your replace - if it returns true the old word as in your RichTextBox:

```
var replaced = Richtextbox.Text.Contains(ReplaceOldWord);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write code as this:

```
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace("old", "new");
if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("old"))
{
  MessageBox.Show("Not replaced");
  //further actions
}
```